# resolv.conf keeps getting reset by something

Tags: networking, resolv.conf

I need help figuring out why my `resolv.conf` keeps changing to this, causing me to not be able to access the outside internet and only the local network:

```
$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 192.168.16.1
domain localdomain
search localdomain
```

I thought I fixed it by getting rid of the loopback interface and adding in the eth0 interface in `/etc/network/interfaces` with the instructions on [jontsai's posterous blog](http://jontsai.posterous.com/howto-debianubuntu-fix-resolvconf-and-network).

I've tried things like doing:

```
$ sudo ifconfig eth0 down
$ sudo ifconfig eth0 up
$ sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
$ sudo dhclient
```

And then things would work temporarily, and eventually the nameserver in resolv.conf would get reverted again.

P.S. I also posted this on [ubuntuforums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=11189763).

---

Edit:
There is at least one other program besides NetworkManager that's writing to `resolv.conf`, and I know this because when I refresh NetworkManager, the `resolv.conf` file that gets generated has a comment that says `# Generated by NetworkManager`, and the version that it keeps changing to does not.

So I am trying this:

`while true; do echo listening; lsof | grep /etc/resolv.conf; echo sleeping; sleep 1; done`

---

Edit 2:

Adding output of files:

```
$ cat /etc/network/interfaces 
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

No such file as `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`

```
$ sudo cat /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Auto\ Ethernet 

[connection]
id=Auto Ethernet
uuid=#######omitted#######
type=802-3-ethernet
autoconnect=true
timestamp=1314377063

[ipv4]
method=auto
ignore-auto-routes=false
ignore-auto-dns=false
dhcp-send-hostname=false
never-default=false

[802-3-ethernet]
speed=0
duplex=full
auto-negotiate=true
mtu=0

[ipv6]
method=ignore
ignore-auto-routes=false
ignore-auto-dns=false
never-default=false
```

Comment: I suspect either a Network Manager bug, or more likely a misconfiguration. What version of Ubuntu are you running? Do you have the `resolvconf` package installed? Post the contents of `/etc/network/interfaces`, `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` and `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/*`.

Comment: I'm running 10.04, no `resolvconf` package. At some point, my DSL modem was going bad (behind router) while my local network was fine, so I might have tried installing `nscd` or `dnsmasq`--they're uninstalled now, but it might have left some artifacts that are interfering?

Comment: Okay, I just rebooted my computer for the first time in 3 weeks, and I think the problem went away. o_O

Comment: Not sure, but I think there was some issue with DHCP server on `vmnet1` or `vmnet8` (NAT and Host-Only)

Comment: This whole discussion is of diminished relevance since Ubuntu 12.04 which introduced resolvconf in the base system, fundamentally changing the way resolv.conf is handled.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I add changes to resolv.conf without them getting overwritten on reboot?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/157154/how-do-i-add-changes-to-resolv-conf-without-them-getting-overwritten-on-reboot).

Comment: This helped me https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using

Answer (score 18):

You can make static additions to `/etc/resolv.conf`. Those additions could override the things that are being automatically added.

First, install the `resolvconf` package.

Then, press Alt+F2 and run `gksudo nautilus`. Open `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head` if you want to add to the start of the file; open `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/tail` if you want to add to the end. Make your changes, save/close the files, and then run `sudo resolvconf -u` to apply the changes.

(Sorry that I don't remember if the settings at the start or end of the file have the highest priority.)

Comment: My network manager changes would be reverted on connecting to any VPN. This allowed me to keep 8.8.8.8 in the resolver list irrespective of which network I connected to.

Answer (score 11):

*(This answer contains ways to investigate what's going on. I may be able to give an actual solution if you use these methods to gather and provide more information.)*

A possible trigger for the seemingly spontaneous updates to `/etc/resolv.conf` is when your DHCP lease is renewed. Check how long you get DHCP leases for (this should appear in the system logs, I think in `/var/log/syslog`).

You can use [auditd](http://packages.ubuntu.com/auditd) [image: Install auditd] to find out what modifies the file. Start the daemon (`sudo service auditd start`) and tell it to watch for modifications to that file:

```
sudo auditctl -w /etc/resolv.conf -p w
```

Audit logs are in `/var/log/audit/audit.log`. You'll see the time the file was modified and the name of the program that modified it.

If you have the `resolvconf` package installed, Network Manager may be stepping on its toes. Try bringing all network interfaces down, then stop Network Manager (`sudo service network-manager stop`), then restart it.

Comment: I believe you are right about DHCP releases. You can change the DHCP settings in the network manager as follows:

Run `nm-connection-editor` in your terminal. Select your interface and hit edit. Under IPv4 settings there should be a method called only DHCP adresses (or something similar). If I'm not mistaken this will allow you to obtain IP adresses through DHCP but not nameservers (you can specify them in the fields below).

Comment: I set my router to map MAC address to static IPs, so the DNS lease is for a long time. The `auditctl` line doesn't work for me, and I believe that the service name for Network Manager is `network-manager` (includes the hyphen). I didn't have a `resolvconf` package installed, but I had stuff inside the `/etc/resolvconf/` folder, and when I compared it to another Ubuntu machine, it didn't have it, so I installed and uninstalled the package, and manually removed that folder. `/etc/resolv.conf` just got rewritten again, so I think getting `auditctl` to work would be very helpful.

Comment: @jontsai The presence of `/etc/resolvconf` is normal even if you don't have the `resolvconf` package, some packages drop hooks in there, and these hooks are only used if `resolvconf` is installed. I've fixed the `auditctl` line, in case the problem appears again.

Comment: I liked the idea of user auditd to find out what was editing the file, but it looks like it get started after the file is already modified.

Answer (score 8):

I had the exact same problem - resolv.conf would be rewritten every time the server was rebooted.

It was caused by DHCP. To set resolv.conf to what I want it to be, I edited `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf` and added the following:

```
supersede domain-name "my.domain.com";
prepend domain-search "my.domain.com";
```

You can actually control quite a bit about your resolv.conf file by making changes to this.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This would be the cleanest solution but for some reason it stopped working on my systems a few years back. I've been stuck with disabling resolvconf script or chattr +i /etc/resolv.conf ever since.

Answer (score 8):

Open up a terminal and type

```
sudo chattr +i /etc/resolv.conf
```

the  +i takes care that the file wont be reseted on a boot even by root.

To undo the above

```
sudo chattr -i /etc/resolv.conf
```

For more

```
man chattr
```

Comment: this did not work for me. Restarting network manager still overwrites /etc/resolv.conf with the DHCP nameservers.

Comment: worked for me on a Debian 9 VM running inside of GCP. yay! thanks!

Comment: worked for me and learned a new skill / Linux feature

Comment: worked for me in ubuntu 22.04

Answer (score 4):

I disable the update of `resolv.conf` by creating a file called `disable_make_resolv_conf` in `/etc/dhcp3/dhclient-enter-hooks.d`

```
#!/bin/sh
make_resolv_conf(){
}
```

It replaces the standard function by the same name that's responsible for the `resolv.conf` refresh.

Comment: Careful.  I thought this was the most elegant solution for me, but it ended up bringing down the entire GCP node because networking couldn't start.  I had to dismount the disk, mount to another node, remove the change, and remount.

Answer (score 4):

Another option that I've had some luck with involves using `resolvconf`.

Add any entries to this file:

```
/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base
```

And they will be added to the `/etc/resolv.conf`.

Thanks to this Ask Ubuntu posting: [How do I include lines in resolv.conf that won't get lost on reboot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/157154/how-do-i-include-lines-in-resolv-conf-that-wont-get-lost-on-reboot)

Answer (score 1):

Late at this but I will post my case as it was different from all of the above.

In my case, `/etc/resolv.conf` is a symlink to `/var/run/NetworkManager/resolv.conf`, and for some reason `cat /etc/resolv.conf` gives me error no such file or directory (maybe because it's empty?)

If I open it with vi and add `nameserver x.x.x.x` it works, but is cleared on reboot.

I tried to edit `/etc/network/interfaces` and add `dns-nameservers x.x.x.x`, changed `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf` and removed under `request` `domain-name-servers`, also edited `prepend domain-name-servers x.x.x.x`.

Resolvconf binary is not installed, `NetworkManager.conf` didn't have anything relevant. But everytime I restarted the machine, there was no domain server.

I'm not sure what the reason is but it seems to have to do with the fact that this is a VBox machine, started by GNS3 and because of that inside VBox setting, I have to leave it with no interface created. Apparently GNS3 creates a "UDP interface" on the fly when I start the machine, provided that I start it from GNS3.

So, to save me from searching endlessly, I just added `echo nameserver x.x.x.x> /etc/resolv.conf` to `/etc/profile`, problem solved (not solved, but worked around hehe). But it could be interesting to know what goes on with that scenario if anyone ran into it.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the file `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`

```sh
cat /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

you can configure NetworkManager to stop resetting resolv.conf with

```sh
sudo sh -c 'echo "
[main]
dns=none
" >> /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf'
cat /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

Now manually change your `/etc/resolv.conf` and test its permanence with

```sh
sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager
# sudo service network-manager restart
cat /etc/resolv.conf
```

Source: https://askubuntu.com/a/623956/452398

Comment: Thank you, adding dns=none fixes the problem in proper way.

Answer (score 0):

Just make entries in your ifcfg-ethX files like so

DNS1=192.168.X.X

DNS2=192.168.X.X

DOMAIN=yourdomain.com

then network manager will post pend those records to the resolv.conf file after you restart the services or restart your box.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone falls in the same case:

I Forgot I set dhcp on an interface inside the file `/etc/network/interfaces`

Networkmanager will modify `/etc/resolv.conf` from the dhcp answer he gets.

hth

Answer (score 0):

When there is `# Generated by NetworkManager` in `/etc/resolv.conf`

Edit Network Manager config:

```
sudo vim /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

in `[main]` section add `rc-manager=unmanaged`:

```
[main]                                                                                                                                   
rc-manager=unmanaged
```

Why?

> `rc-manager` -
>   Set the resolv.conf management mode. The default value depends on NetworkManager build options, and this version of NetworkManager was build with a default of "symlink".
>
> (...)
>
> `unmanaged`: don't touch `/etc/resolv.conf`.

Config reference for more info: https://developer.gnome.org/NetworkManager/stable/NetworkManager.conf.html

Then edit your `/etc/resolv.conf` and restart Network Manager to see, if `/etc/resolv.conf` stays untouched:

```
sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager
```

or

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

than:

```
cat /etc/resolv.conf
```

If procedure failed and `/etc/resolv.conf` was overwritten during Network Manager restart try adding `dns=none` to `[main]` section in config as https://askubuntu.com/a/1150326/364772 said

Answer (score 0):

for me the file that was re-setting was `sudo nano /etc/systemd/resolved.conf` 
and here 
`/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf`

i changed it to `8.8.8.8` based on google search.

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple. `/etc/resolv.conf` is managed by `systemd`, so you have to adapt the file that controls this file:

```
sudo nano /etc/systemd/resolv.conf
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

on my RaspberryPi

```
sudo nano /etc/dhcpd.conf
```

add to the end (or modify if already exists)

```
static domain_name_servers=8.8.4.4 8.8.8.8
```

Ctrl + X + Y to save and exit.
After reboot you're good to go

Answer (score 0):

for me, I found out that it was tailscale

```
# resolv.conf(5) file generated by tailscale
# For more info, see https://tailscale.com/s/resolvconf-overwrite
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
```