# internet issues after upgrading to Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, dhclient

I upgraded to Ubuntu 12.10 using update manager. After the upgrade, the wifi gets connected but would not display any webpages. If I ping 8.8.8.8 or google.com, there is response.

I managed to fix this problem by using the command `sudo dhclient wlan0`. But, now the problem is that every time I switch wireless networks, I have to give that command. how do I make this permanent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely the symbolic link /etc/resolv.conf -> ../run/resolvconf/resolv.conf is missing on your system. To restore it, do the following in a terminal.

```
sudo apt-get install resolvconf
sudo dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf
```

If you want to use 8.8.8.8 as your nameserver then set up either ifup or NetworkManager to use that nameserver address for the interface(s) that it brings up.

If you use ifup then edit /etc/network/interfaces and, in the stanza for the interface in question, add the line "dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8"; then ifdown the interface and ifup it again.

If you use NetworkManager then open the connection editor and add 8.8.8.8 as an additional nameserver address (network indicator | Edit Connections... | Wireless | myconnection | Edit... | IPv4 Settings | Additional DNS servers).

Answer (score 1):

You need to edit your DNS configuration.
Type `gksudo gedit /etc/resolv.conf` in the terminal. Add your DNS ( eg 8.8.8.8 ) in place of 127.0.0.1.
As pointed out, this configuration may be overwritten. Use [resolvconf](http://www.stgraber.org/2012/02/24/dns-in-ubuntu-12-04/) to modify this file.

Comment: I changed it to `gedit` for the sake of future inexperienced users.

Comment: resolv.conf gets overwritten sometimes. Use resolvconf instead. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/130452/how-do-i-add-a-dns-server-via-resolv-conf

Comment: @ObsessiveSSOℲ  resolv.conf is not present starting Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: @Ubuntuser Why are you addressing this post toward me? I did nor write it. Please address it to the author, Ignite.

Comment: @Ubuntuser It is present. To know more about it just type man resolv.conf

Comment: @Ubuntuser see my answer [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/201603/generate-resolv-conf-file/201613#201613) and it will not be overwritten.

Comment: @ĭgnĭtE: As `user68186` said, `resolv.conf` gets overwritten sometimes. I will try to use solution provided by `NikTh` and see if it works. Thanks

Comment: This answer is wrong. In Ubuntu since 12.04, resolv.conf is dynamically generated by the resolvconf utility and, as the comment in the file says in FULL CAPS, you should not edit the file by hand.