# Ethernet Problems - Realtek RTL8101E/RTL8102E

Tags: networking, drivers, bluetooth, broadcom, intel-wireless

This problem has been going on for a few months now. After failed troubleshooting (time and again), I'm finally giving in, and asking you for help. I would like to prefix this by saying that Ubuntu is now the operating system I prefer and use regularly.

I have scoured the askubuntu forums and have tried many of the solutions offered, yet none have solved these problems. ndiswrapper does not work, either.

Any help with this problem would be greatly appreciated :)

**Edit 1:** As a bit more detail, my wireless can only connect to 1 router (ssid: NETGEAR-2.4G). I can't connect to the second router in our home (ssid: 4NXG). I'm using my wireless connection to reach these forums, but Ethernet still does not work. I would like to resolve the Ethernet and Wireless problems, if possible.

**Edit 2:** On Elder Geek's advice, I'm editing this question to only deal with the ethernet problems.

**Edit 3:** Added additional lspci information, as requested.

**Edit 5:** Added even more info, zomg so much info

**Current Problems**

- Ethernet shows "Connected", but there is no connectivity. Rarely, ethernet will start working out of the blue. Then immediately stop working again.
- Router sees my computer (when accessed remotely via 192.168.1.1)
- Pinging google.com or any ipaddress results in packet loss.
- Port forwarding does not work

**Symptoms (Timeline)**

- January 2015 - Linux Mint Rebecca Installed. Wireless worked fine,
  Ethernet worked fine.
- Early February 2015 - Port forwarding suddenly failed.
- Mid February 2015 - Wired connectivity failed. Only wireless works.
- I have installed Ubuntu 14.04.02 (current OS), Debian 7.8.0, and Linux Mint Rebecca. All fresh installs have failed to achieve Ethernet connectivity.
- While connected to the Ethernet, the wireless router sees my computer, and my computer says that it is "connected". Yet all queries of any webpage simply times out. Pinging google.com results in 100% packet loss.

**System Specs.**

### route -n

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0
```

### cat /etc/resolv.conf

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 127.0.1.1
search home
```

### lspci -k

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller (rev 09)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 0597
    Kernel driver in use: ivb_uncore
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 0597
    Kernel driver in use: i915
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 0597
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 0597
    Kernel driver in use: mei_me
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 0597
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 0597
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev c4)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 0597
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM76 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 0597
    Kernel driver in use: lpc_ich
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 0597
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 0597
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 0597
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
02:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1704 802.11n + BT 4.0
    Kernel driver in use: wl
```

### lspci -nn | grep 0200

```
01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 05)
```

### ip link

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether ec:f4:bb:94:2b:f6 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 54:35:30:e2:63:27 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

### iw dev

```
phy#0
Interface wlan0
    ifindex 3
    type managed
```

### iwconfig

```
eth0      no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11abg  ESSID:"NETGEAR-2.4-G"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: 30:46:9A:67:34:2F   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

### lsmod

```
Module                  Size  Used by
bnep                   19624  2 
rfcomm                 69509  8 
dm_crypt               23216  0 
nls_iso8859_1          12713  1 
wl                   6367833  0 
uvcvideo               81073  0 
videobuf2_vmalloc      13216  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops       13362  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
btusb                  32497  0 
rtsx_usb_ms            18697  0 
videobuf2_core         59104  1 uvcvideo
bluetooth             446409  22 bnep,btusb,rfcomm
memstick               16966  1 rtsx_usb_ms
v4l2_common            15681  1 videobuf2_core
videodev              153793  3 uvcvideo,v4l2_common,videobuf2_core
6lowpan_iphc           18702  1 bluetooth
media                  21903  2 uvcvideo,videodev
dell_wmi               12761  0 
sparse_keymap          13948  1 dell_wmi
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     47548  1 
snd_hda_codec_realtek    77467  1 
snd_hda_codec_generic    68937  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_intel          30469  3 
snd_hda_controller     31056  1 snd_hda_intel
snd_hda_codec         139682  5 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_controller
snd_hwdep              17698  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm               104112  4 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_controller
cfg80211              494362  1 wl
snd_seq_midi           13564  0 
dell_laptop            18168  0 
snd_seq_midi_event     14899  1 snd_seq_midi
dcdbas                 14928  1 dell_laptop
snd_rawmidi            30876  1 snd_seq_midi
intel_rapl             18783  0 
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    14205  0 
intel_powerclamp       18823  0 
snd_seq                63074  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
coretemp               13441  0 
kvm_intel             143590  0 
kvm                   452043  1 kvm_intel
crct10dif_pclmul       14307  0 
snd_seq_device         14497  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
snd_timer              29562  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
crc32_pclmul           13133  0 
ghash_clmulni_intel    13230  0 
cryptd                 20359  1 ghash_clmulni_intel
snd                    79468  17 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device
joydev                 17393  0 
serio_raw              13483  0 
mei_me                 19696  0 
lpc_ich                21093  0 
shpchp                 37047  0 
mei                    87875  1 mei_me
soundcore              15047  2 snd,snd_hda_codec
mac_hid                13227  0 
parport_pc             32741  0 
ppdev                  17671  0 
lp                     17759  0 
parport                42348  3 lp,ppdev,parport_pc
rtsx_usb_sdmmc         27787  0 
rtsx_usb               20987  2 rtsx_usb_sdmmc,rtsx_usb_ms
hid_generic            12559  0 
usbhid                 52616  0 
hid                   110426  2 hid_generic,usbhid
uas                    23159  0 
usb_storage            66545  1 uas
psmouse               106561  0 
wmi                    19193  1 dell_wmi
i915                  905966  3 
r8169                  71694  0 
ahci                   34062  3 
video                  20128  1 i915
i2c_algo_bit           13413  1 i915
drm_kms_helper         61574  1 i915
mii                    13934  1 r8169
drm                   311018  5 i915,drm_kms_helper
libahci                32424  1 ahci
```

### ifconfig (while connected to ethernet only)

```
james@james-Inspiron-3521:~$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr ec:f4:bb:94:2b:f6  
          inet addr:192.168.1.2  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::eef4:bbff:fe94:2bf6/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:257 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:282 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:68075 (68.0 KB)  TX bytes:32489 (32.4 KB)
          Interrupt:42 Base address:0xa000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:430 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:430 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:41427 (41.4 KB)  TX bytes:41427 (41.4 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 54:35:30:e2:63:27  
          inet6 addr: fe80::5635:30ff:fee2:6327/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:676 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:4651
          TX packets:746 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:484022 (484.0 KB)  TX bytes:107610 (107.6 KB)
          Interrupt:17
```

Comment: If pinging google.com fails and pinging 173.194.46.40 succeeds your network problem is DNS

Comment: --- 173.194.46.40 ping statistics ---
11 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 10079ms

Comment: are you connected via wire or wireless?

Comment: when I pinged that ip address, i was connected to only the wired network. right now, i'm connected to wireless (the only way to access the internet currently).

Comment: Your question is a bit on the "too broad side"  Bluetooth, ethernet, wifi 3 different questions, your router question is likely off topic. I'll answer the ethernet question so at least you can have reliable connectivity while you [edit] this question to be a single question and search for the existing answers for the others.

Comment: Ok. Editing it now ...

Comment: What exact Dell laptop/machine is this? It appears to have a very unfriendly hardware configuration for use in free software. Both your wired and wireless cards have only poor support in Linux. Please also include what kernel are you currently using. 14.04 can have both 3.13 and 3.16 kernel (depending on the installation path). Installing 3.16 from the Utopic HWE backport can help you out for ethernet I think.

Comment: Dell Inspiron 15 3521, Kernel 3.16.0-34-generic

Comment: I was forced into using Linux after having huge permission problems and corruption on Windows 8. I got sick of it, made the switch to Linux, and haven't regretted it for a minute (even with these networking bugs).

Comment: May we see: `lspci -nn | grep 0200`? Thanks.

Comment: @chili555 ... I added the information you requested

Comment: What do you mean by "the wireless router sees my computer"? Do you just mean a light turns on on the router for that port? My thought on this is it could be a hardware problem, maybe something has gone wrong with the ethernet card itself? I know that not all of the wires in an ethernet connection have to be fully connected before link lights on equipment turn on, even if data can't be sent.

Comment: I'll access the verizon router via Remote Administration. I go into the connections page in the router, where it displays all connections to the router (ethernet or otherwise). It shows that my computer, with system information (james-inspiron-3521), is actively connected to the router. It sees that my computer is connected, and is receiving data about the computer itself. I spent 4 hours talking with verizon technical support about this problem, and they've assured me that the router is properly configured.

Comment: what's your `ifconfig` look like when you are connected by wire?

Comment: @ElderGeek .. I added the data you requested. Thank you for your help, in advance.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry for not requesting this to begin with (too many years supporting windows with `ipconfig` is my only excuse) but I also need the output of `route -n` and `cat /etc/resolv.conf`also when only connected by wire.

Comment: no, thank you! I added the information you requested @ElderGeek ... please let me know if there's any other specs I can grab. also: if we solve this problem, please edit your answer below with the solution and i'll happily mark it as the answer that solved my problem (so nobody else needs to go through this nightmare)

Answer (score -1):

Download and install the LINUX driver for kernel 3.x and 2.6.x and 2.4.x found [here](http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=7&PFid=7&Level=5&Conn=4&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false#RTL8100E/RTL8101E/RTL8102E-GR/RTL8103E%28L%29%3Cbr%3ERTL8102E%28L%29/RTL8101E/RTL8103T%3Cbr%3ERTL8401/RTL8401P/RTL8105E%3Cbr%3ERTL8402/RTL8106E)

Make a temp folder on your desktop and extract the content into it. You'll see this:[image: realtek]

Open a terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>

change to the directory of the content. In my case.

`cd ~/Desktop/temp/r8101-1.026.00/`

then issue the command `sudo ./autorun.sh` This will install the driver that supports your ethernet chipset.

Open network connections, choose the wired connection and choose[image: eth1] edit and insure your settings match the above.

Comment: -1 for instructions on installing drivers from upstream. 99/100 times this is already in the mainline kernel and it just requires some backport from the Ubuntu repositories. Installing it manually like this is very much error prone, especially when upgrading the kernel later. It is very much adviced against to take this way unless you really know what you are doing.

Comment: @gertvdijk my apologies, this has worked for me repeatedly. I'd like to see some statistics backing up the 99/100 claim as my results have been quite different. As always, feel free to provide a better answer.

Comment: I did everything you instructed above and it all installed properly. I disabled wifi and tried using the ethernet connection (this didn't work). I rebooted the system (disabled wifi) and tried connecting again to any webpage. Still no luck :/

Comment: According to your post, your router is at 192.168.1.1 and your system is at 192.168.1.2, your default gateway is correct but since pinging google fails, DNS is not functioning. Open Network Connections. You will be editing your ethernet connection. Based on the RX/TX numbers I see for the wire I'm assuming that it's set for DHCP. Usually DNS is provided by the router in this case from your ISP in which case your configuration should show 192.168.1.1 for DNS. You can manually add your ISP's DNS server in the configuration here and can also add 8.8.8.8 (Googles public DNS).

Comment: If the above is all accurate you should be able to ping 192.168.1.1 to insure that the cable is good. (it looks like it is and DNS appears to be your only problem)

Comment: @ElderGeek may I ask something, kind of off topic here, but I've noticed there's `nameserver 127.0.1.1` and `search home` lines in OP's resolv.conf file. What exactly `nameserver 127.0.1.1` does there?

Comment: @Serg 127.0.1.1 is the local host and is the default entry in resolv.conf  since Ubuntu 12.10 For more see http://askubuntu.com/questions/382020/how-do-i-remove-localhost-nameserver-from-resolv-conf and http://askubuntu.com/questions/201603/should-i-edit-my-resolv-conf-file-to-fix-wrong-dns-problem/208027#208027

Comment: @ElderGeek .. I'm sorry, networking is absolutely not my forte. Would you be able to give me a more detailed how-to for fixing these DNS problems? I tried adding the 192.168.1.1 but I don't know what to do for the netmask and gateway

Comment: Edited answer. posting an image may be easiest for you, typical netmask for a 192.168 family of addresses will be 255.255.255.0 but if you are using DHCP you shouldn't require it. If your router is operating properly, DNS should be 192.168.1.1 If it's not, we can try a manual configuration.

Comment: I ensured that my connection is Automatic DHCP and matches the image. However, I still am unable to ping any ip addresses. Here is a pic of my router's configuration: http://i.imgur.com/Jn4jsA3.png

Comment: @ElderGeek : after doing a bit more research, I get the impression that the bridge network connections in the router are important. here's a link for the specific bridge settings .. i.imgur.com/JG897j0.png