# How to remove nameservers from resolv.conf after vpn disconnect?

Tags: networking, dns, openvpn

I have this `resolv.conf` even after disconnecting from VPN server (connection was established using `openvpn --config <path>.ovpn`):

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
# 127.0.0.53 is the systemd-resolved stub resolver.
# run "systemd-resolve --status" to see details about the actual nameservers
nameserver 10.4.X.X
nameserver 10.4.Y.Y
nameserver 127.0.0.53
search Z.ac.in
```

I want to get rid of `search Z.ac.in` and the `10.4` ns. However, I can't find them in `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/{head,base,tail}`. I even did `grep 10.4.X.X` inside the `/etc/resolvconf` directory with no result. Similarly, my `/etc/network/interfaces` file is mostly empty:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

For now I have just been restarting my pc to remove them. But how to remove them properly from the resolv.conf file?

Comment: Which vpn are you using?

Comment: @kashish I am using openvpn with this command `sudo openvpn --config <path>.ovpn`. Version information: `OpenVPN 2.4.4 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH/PKTINFO] [AEAD] built on May 14 2019`

Comment: What OS and version?

Comment: @rtaft Ubuntu 18.04 (Linux gt 5.3.0-62-generic #56~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 24 16:17:03 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux)

Comment: Do you have directive "up" and "down" in your <path>.ovpn? If you have something like `up /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf` or `up /etc/openvpn/update-systemd-resolved`, make sure you have openvpn client call the script when you disconnect, with a `down /etc/...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sudo systemd-resolve --revert --interface vpn0` to reset resolv.conf after getting off the VPN.

If that works, you can run it automatically when disconnecting from the VPN by creating `/etc/network/if-post-down.d/vpn0` with the following contents:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ "$IFACE" = "vpn0" ]; then
    systemd-resolve --revert --interface vpn0
fi
```

Then
`chmod 755 /etc/network/if-post-down.d/vpn0` to allow it to execute.

Replace `vpn0` in all above with your vpn interface.

Answer (score 1):

Probably, these settings are cleared when you force a network-manager restart.  Try
`sudo service network-manager restart`

Still a rather brute solution but one level better than pc restart.  If it works, it can be automated by putting a script in /etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d with contents:

```
#!/bin/sh
if [[ "$2"="vpn-down" ]]; then  
    /usr/sbin/service network-manager restart
fi
```

You could even diversify on the network interface by using parameter $1 in the test.  Do not forget to make the script executable by :
`sudo chmod +x /etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/<yourscriptname>`

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
sudo vi /run/resolvconf/interface/NetworkManager
```

You ma also use nano editor, Remove or replace nameserver and then run

```
sudo resolvconf -u
```

For more information see [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/382020/how-do-i-remove-localhost-nameserver-from-resolv-conf) or [this](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/remove-nameserver-line-from-resolv-conf-4175674701/).