# (16.04) Connected to internet but not working

Tags: networking, internet, connection

So, everything was fine until I turned on my laptop today and then all pages gave me "Server not found". Can't even connect to the software updater. It's not a computer or internet problem because:
-internet works in my windows partition (same computer) and other devices at home
-tried to connect using the shared mobile internet from my phone and it didn't work either

Tried both wireless and wired

So ubuntu's internet broke just because. I tried different DNS, ips and whatnot but no luck. I'm not Linux expert so please help me. I tried to ping 8.8.8.8 in the terminal and get 64 bytes in every line, with a time averaging 39 ms and ttl=59. I have no idea what any of that means. This is quite frustrating.

EDIT: so I tried briefly to edit resolv.conf (it was blank) and added nameservers, it worked for a while, then stopped working, and now It works again. What gives? Let's see how much does it last. Leaving to the mods the best course of action regarding this thread

Comment: Are you not trying to use wifi and wired connections at same time? What is the output of your resolv.conf when your internet connection drops down?

Comment: You might find https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-problem.html useful.

Comment: You should not edit resolv.conf by hand.

Answer (score 1):

In this case the answer is "**Don't do that**"

You should not edit /etc/resolv.conf by hand. In fact the default content tells you that as shown below.

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 127.0.1.1
```

There is related detail available on this topic [here.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/201603/should-i-edit-my-resolv-conf-file-to-fix-wrong-dns-problem) as well as [here.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58781/resolv-conf-keeps-getting-reset-by-something)