# Fixing resolv.conf from Comcast Meddling

Tags: 14.04, dns, resolv.conf

So I'm trying to get Ruby on Rails set-up on my development machine (with a fresh install of ubuntu 14.04).

Everything is going well until I get this lovely message from the terminal:

```
$ gem install rails
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError)
    Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - connect(2) for
 "your-dns-needs-immediate-attention.network" port 443 
(https://your-dns-needs-immediate-attention.network/
quick/Marshal.4.8/rails-4.1.6.gemspec.rz)
```

After frantically Duck-Duck-Go-ing all over I found out a [lot](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/1001) of people are having the issue.

Luckily, the awesome folks on SO have found this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25583938/gem-install-rails-fails-with-dns-error) (See answer 2) but I've been trying for a while to get my `resolv.conf` file free of the offending line.

Since I can't overwrite the `/etc/resolv.conf` file, after inspecting the `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/` directory I only have the base and head files which leads me to believe that the actual contents of the file are being generated elsewhere.

Speaking of contents:

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 127.0.1.1
search home.network
```

And the offending line is `search home.network` (according to the people who answered the above linked solution).

Question is, how do I remove this line of text in a persistent way? Is there some kind of magic option or flag to a command that will save the day?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I include lines in resolv.conf that won't get lost on reboot?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/157154/how-do-i-include-lines-in-resolv-conf-that-wont-get-lost-on-reboot)

Comment: I have looked at that answer as well but it does not describe how to remove a line generated by ```resolvconf```

Comment: Have you tried it though?

Comment: @Nattgew after reading the comments of the top-voted answer, I still don't see how changing or adding lines will solve removing a line. Since the last search is the only one used, that may hold a key to what I am trying to solve but I'm not sure what a sensible insertion would be.

Comment: Insert the line you want, hopefully it will override the wrong info. Look at the second answer too.

Comment: @Nattgew, problem is I don't what line I DO want, just a line I'm told I don't want so ```gem``` will work. That second answer was a bit cryptic to me since I'm not at all sure what I'm doing with the ```dhclient.conf``` file which doesn't have any mention of ```dns-nameservers``` per a search in the file's contents.

Comment: The SO post says it should be `http://hds1.ma.comcast.net`. Nothing about `dns-nameservers` in `dhclient.conf` is a good sign.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you have a Linux system.
But regardless if it's Windows, Ubuntu, or some other OS - here's the "workaround" until Comcast can get things to work.

Do NOT get your DNS servers dynamically from Comcast (which they'll give you `75.75.75.75` and `75.75.76.76`)  --

Rather, statically configure your DNS servers and use the two Google public DNS servers:  `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4`

Not sure how Comcast got around this, but even when I had the Comcast servers and I tried to resolve using Google server on the nslookup command line `nslookup www.yahoo.com 8.8.8.8` --  my results still came back in error with the `127.0.53.53` as the address.  (Yet, I could ping www.yahoo.com and it would get the IP address properly).

However, I noticed when I VPN'ed into my office and was using my VPN connection to resolve hostnames, I would receive expected results.

Hence, I disabled my PC from using the automatically obtained DNS servers -- strapped the servers to Google -- and I'm getting expected results.

This article discusses Comcast's current challenges: http://domainincite.com/17401-comcast-users-report-name-collision-bugs