# Failed to install sqlite3 for Asterisk 11

Tags: 14.04, server, 32-bit, asterisk

I'm trying to install Asterisk 11 in Ubuntu Server 14.04 32 bits, and I can't to install sqlite3 for I use Asterisk 11 in this machine.

Please see below the message:

```
ubuntu@asterisk-ubuntu:/usr/src/asterisk-11.16.0$ LANG=C sudo apt-get install sqlite3 libsqlite3-dev 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Suggested packages:
sqlite3-doc 
The following NEW packages will be installed:
libsqlite3-dev sqlite3
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 471 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1558 kB of additional disk space will be used.    
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main libsqlite3-dev i386 3.8.2-1ubuntu2
Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main sqlite3 i386 3.8.2-1ubuntu2
Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/sqlite3/libsqlite3-dev_3.8.2-1ubuntu2_i386.deb  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/sqlite3/sqlite3_3.8.2-1ubuntu2_i386.deb  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

How can I install this sqlite3 for Ubuntu?

Thanks so much

```
  ubuntu@asterisk-ubuntu:/usr/src/asterisk-11.16.0$ sudo ping 91.189.91.23
  PING 91.189.91.23 (91.189.91.23) 56(84) bytes of data.
  64 bytes from 91.189.91.23: icmp_seq=1 ttl=53 time=146 ms
  64 bytes from 91.189.91.23: icmp_seq=2 ttl=53 time=211 ms
  64 bytes from 91.189.91.23: icmp_seq=3 ttl=53 time=190 ms
  64 bytes from 91.189.91.23: icmp_seq=4 ttl=53 time=145 ms
  ^C
  --- 91.189.91.23 ping statistics ---
  4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3003ms
  rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 145.907/173.793/211.788/28.546 ms
```

Comment: Whats the output of `ping archive.ubuntu.com`?

Comment: buntu@asterisk-ubuntu:/usr/src/asterisk-11.16.0$ ping archive.ubuntu.com
ping: unknown host archive.ubuntu.com

Comment: Whats the output of `ping 91.189.91.23`?

Comment: see above @heemayl

Comment: You are having a DNS issue (not an `apt` issue)..Run `printf "\nnameserver 8.8.8.8" | sudo tee -a /etc/resolv.conf` and then try `ping archive.ubuntu.com`..

Comment: Let me put that as an answer in details..

Comment: humm If I use your command will not resolve, I put manually in /etc/revolv.conf the DNS

Comment: Check my answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are having a DNS issue, the name resolution is failing. Either you do not have set a valid name server address or your name server is having problem resulting in name resolution failure.

You can run the following command to temporarily set Google's free name server as the DNS server but it is highly recommended that you use your ISP provided DNS server address.

```
printf "\nnameserver 8.8.8.8" | sudo tee -a /etc/resolv.conf
```

This will add "nameserver 8.8.8.8" to `/etc/resov.conf`. This is temporary i.e. will not survive a reboot, you can [follow this](https://askubuntu.com/q/157154/216503) to permanently set DNS server address(es).