# nameserver goes missing from /etc/resolv.conf

Tags: dns, resolv.conf

I have a problem where the line `nameserver 8.8.8.8` just disappears from my `/etc/resolv.conf`.

This might happen every few days or so and I haven't noticed anything that would be linked to this issue. Then I add it back manually and restart my forever looping scripts. This is pretty annoying to do and I'd like to know why this happens.

Answer (score 2):

To add permanent lines in `/etc/resolv.conf` you could install the `resolvconf` command line:

```
sudo apt install resolvconf
```

then you have to edit `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head` and add the permanent lines you need. For example:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 1.1.1.1
```

and finally run these commands:

```
sudo resolvconf --enable-updates
sudo resolvconf -u
```

Maybe you need to restart the network interface after that, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

At reboot `/etc/resolve.conf` usually regenerated and can be rewritten / created on occasion by your DHCP or other services. You can try to disable getting `dns-nameservers` from your DHCP server if it's the case.

`dhclient` usually overcomes most `resolvconf` files. So updating your `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf` and `/etc/network/interfaces` files can work.

[Answers and opinions for a similar issue can be found here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/157154/how-do-i-include-lines-in-resolv-conf-that-wont-get-lost-on-reboot)

Comment: I forgot to mention but this happens without rebooting. Uptime on this machine is 35days and I remember this happening a few times during this uptime.

Comment: Well you can change the write permission of `resolve.conf` to make sure it's not writable. Not the best solution probably but worked in my case sometime ago. You can simply use `chattr +i /etc/resolv.conf` to make it write protected, `chattr -i /etc/resolv.conf` to make it writable again. About why it happens, I can list numerous reasons. It's probably faster and easier to just overcome it rather than searching for the root cause.

Comment: using chattr on resolv.conf is fixing the wrong problem.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple services including netplan, network-manager, and dhcpd all need to make changes to resolv.conf to reflect current network configuration.

Typically in an ubuntu system, the systemd-resolve and resolvconf services try to juggle this, and you will find that the file `/etc/resolv.conf` is actually a symlink to `/var/run/resolvconf/resolv.conf`.

If you want to make permanent changes to this file, you need to make the changes in one of the controlling subsystems, such as netplan or network-manager.

If you don't want that file to be automatically managed, you can delete the symlink and recreate it as a regular file.  However, this may break things like VPN, DHCP, and dynamic network changes you get when you move from one physical network to another.