# network manager: how to stop nm updating /etc/resolv.conf

Tags: dns, resolv.conf

I do not want network manager to add DNS servers received from DHCP to my `/etc/resolv.conf`.

When configuring from GUI/Connections/IPV4 and choose the method Automatic (address only) it still adds DNS servers received via DHCP.

Is it possible to do it per connection (specific ssid ?)

Comment: If you choose method "Automatic (DHCP) addresses only" then NetworkManager won't, or shouldn't, change resolv.conf when activating that connection. If NetworkManager does in fact add addresses to resolv.conf despite the "addresses only" setting then there is a bug in NetworkManager and you should report that bug using Launchpad. To stop NetworkManager from changing resolv.conf you should select "Automatic (DHCP) addresses only" in all connection configurations that become active on your system.

Comment: You can either use GUI in the IPv4 settings on the connection and choose "adddresses only" in the mode, or, do what it does yourself by editing the corresponding connection file in /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/ and adding ignore-auto-dns=true  line to the [ipv4] section.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

One way to stop Network Manager from adding dns-servers to `/etc/resolv.conf` file is to do this:

First open the nm conf file `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`:

```
sudo vim /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

And add this to the `[main]` section:

```
dns=none
rc-manager=unmanaged
```

Save and exit.

Comment: `/etc/resolv.conf` is typically a symlink - are you sure making it immutable makes the target of the link also immutable?

Comment: Yes, `/etc/resolv.conf` is usually a symlink and the chattr method won't work. So I would suggest removing that part of the answer.

Comment: from man page (NetworkManager.conf, 15.04 ):  `The default if the key is not specified. NetworkManager will update
           resolv.conf to reflect the nameservers provided by currently active
           connections.  ` Good, but I would just comment that line out instead of setting to `none`

Comment: This doesn't work for me in debian jessie

Comment: What version of NM does this work on? Might want to note it, because it doesn't work on older stuff.

Comment: This does not work on Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: I had to `sudo service network-manager restart` before the change to the .conf file took effect.

Comment: Worked for me on Ubuntu 18.10, I had to run restart network manager as Chris above stated.

Comment: Thank you so much! worked like a charm on 18.04.. Finally!!!

Comment: I've done this but now `resolvconf` is updating `resolv.conf`... I edited `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head` and my edits also appeared on `/etc/resolv.conf` How do I stop that? @krt Thanks very much.

Comment: Stop+Disable systemd-resolved, remove the symlink, create a real /etc/resolv.conf file and set dns=none as mentioned, and reboot. Work ok on Fedora 33.

Comment: Did you mean `unmanaged`? Because `none` just rewrite `resolv.conf` into an empty file.

Comment: sudo service network-manager restart is a must, i even restart but still not working

Comment: I have a related question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1453982/ubuntu-22-04-1-nameservers-keep-getting-overwritten

Comment: For me, `sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager.service` was the command for restarting. Unfortunately, the problem at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1453982/ubuntu-22-04-1-nameservers-keep-getting-overwritten still happened even after adding the above lines to the `[main]` section.

Answer (score 7):

`/etc/resolv.conf` is symlinked to `/run/resolvconf/resolv.conf`. NetworkManager doesn't update /etc/resolv.conf directly (only updates /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf). So:

- remove symlink (`rm /etc/resolv.conf`)
- write you own version of `/etc/resolv.conf`

Comment: I know this is a ubuntu forum but while googling for centos this was still my first google result, so posting comment for future centos googlers. this did not solve my problem on centos. It appears the centos network manager is directly working on /etc/resolv.conf.

Comment: This is not true for Debian Stretch most certainly. It removes your file and replaces it with another symlink. Very annoying.

Comment: Here is one for (virtualized) Fedora 25 using `nmcli`: In `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-ens3` we see that `PEERDNS=yes` which means (in this case, wrong) DNS information is obtained by DHCP, and it ends up in `/etc/resolv.conf`. I just want 127.0.0.1 as nameserver. Running `nmcli con mod ens3 ipf4.ignore-auto.dns yes` result in `PEERDNS=no` in the interface config file. However `/etc/resolv.conf` still has stray `namseserver`entry, so if have to restart the connection `nmcli con down ens3; nmcli con up ens3`. See also: https://www.certdepot.net/rhel7-configure-ipv4-addresses/

Comment: On Ubuntu 18.04, restarting 'service network-manager restart' will cause NM to overwrite /etc/resolv.conf even if it is a hard file and not a symlink.

Comment: The symlink and (/run/resolvconf/resolv.conf) does not existing for Arch linux

Answer (score 5):

My personal favorite is to use line `supersede domain-name-servers` in `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf`. No matter what dns access point provides , your ubuntu will always use those dns specified in `dhclient.conf`

Sample from my file

```
#send host-name "andare.fugue.com";
send host-name = gethostname();
#send dhcp-client-identifier 1:0:a0:24:ab:fb:9c;
#send dhcp-lease-time 3600;
#supersede domain-name "fugue.com home.vix.com";
supersede domain-name-servers 208.67.220.220;
#prepend domain-name-servers 127.0.0.1;
request subnet-mask, broadcast-address, time-offset, routers,
    domain-name, domain-name-servers, domain-search, host-name,
    dhcp6.name-servers, dhcp6.domain-search,
    netbios-name-servers, netbios-scope, interface-mtu,
    rfc3442-classless-static-routes, ntp-servers,
    dhcp6.fqdn, dhcp6.sntp-servers;
#require subnet-mask, domain-name-servers;
```

Comment: creating a line as described (using server 8.8.8.8) does not work on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: @LuizAngioletti 18.04  is using different type of network manager application, called `netplan`.  This answer was written for pre-18.04  releases.  I may update it later, though.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case I have done a little script to do that automatically (here with google DNS) for every ethernet/wireless connections:

```
nmcli -g name,type connection  show  --active | awk -F: '/ethernet|wireless/ { print $1 }' | while read connection
do
  nmcli con mod "$connection" ipv6.ignore-auto-dns yes
  nmcli con mod "$connection" ipv4.ignore-auto-dns yes
  nmcli con mod "$connection" ipv4.dns "8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4"
  nmcli con down "$connection" && nmcli con up "$connection"
done
```