# Syslog flooded with systemd-resolved messages "Using degraded feature set"

Tags: 17.04, syslog, systemd-resolved

Lately my syslog is being flooded with these messages:

```
localhost systemd-resolved[1632]: Using degraded feature set (TCP) for DNS server 127.0.1.1.
```

I'm on Ubuntu 17.04. `resolv.conf` is auto-configured, i.e. I did not mess with it.

Question: How can I stop the flooding of my syslog? It grows to several gigabytes, filling up my root partition.

Comment: That is a normal message if you use "bind" and did not configure it. So did you install that perhaps? If so see https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-bind-as-a-caching-or-forwarding-dns-server-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: There's only the `bind9-host` package on my system and when I try to remove it, it wants to remove `ubuntu-standard` and some other things along with it.

Comment: I have the same issue on my system, and also, DNS resolution no longer works. I haven't figured out the cause yet, but I believe NetworkManager incorrectly puts `nameserver 127.0.1.1` into my `/etc/resolv.conf`. If I understand it correctly, it should only do that when `dnsmasq` is being used, but I don't have that installed.

Answer (score 2):

I had an old record lying in my */etc/resolvconf.conf* that injected `127.0.0.1` whenever network went up:

```
# /etc/resolvconf.conf
# Configuration for resolvconf(8)
# See resolvconf.conf(5) for details

resolv_conf=/etc/resolv.conf
# If you run a local name server, you should uncomment the below line and
# configure your subscribers configuration files below.
name_servers=127.0.0.1
```

So commented it out, then ran `resolvconf -u` and my issue was fixed. Currently using systemd-networkd, so dont't know for sure if this will help OP's specific case.

However, NetworkManager has a setting to make it stop updating *resolv.conf*:

```
[main]
dns=none
```

More information in another question at [network manager: how to stop nm updating /etc/resolv.conf](https://askubuntu.com/questions/623940/network-manager-how-to-stop-nm-updating-etc-resolv-conf#623956)

**Update:**
The same kind of message appears when my upstream DNS servers are down/not responding. However, containing the upstream IP addresses on a round-robin basis between the server alternatives.

**Update #2:**
When using `systemd-networkd`, if you've opted to use the following DNS settings for your interface in `/etc/systemd/network/<iface>.network`:

```
[DHCP]
UseDNS=true
```

which is the default setting, then it will not be using your local `systemd-resolved` instance, but instead use the a server from DHCP. Set `UseDNS=false` to use your systemd-resolver. Read `man systemd.network` for detailed information.

Comment: There's no `/etc/resolvconf.conf` on my Ubuntu 17.04 system, and the  (few) files in the subdirectories of `/etc/resolvconf` do not contain this line. I'd like to keep NM updating my resolv.conf so I can use the most proximal name servers depending on the current network environment that I am in (this is on a laptop).

Answer (score 0):

It may be that your /etc/resolv.conf is not pointing to /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf, which is where this information is now managed. You can check this using:

```
ls -l /etc/resolv.conf
```

This should come back with something like:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 27 Jan 22 08:50 /etc/resolv.conf -> /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf
```

If not, then check your system has this file:

```
ls -l /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf
```

And if so, switch to using it:

```
sudo rm /etc/resolv.conf; sudo ln -s /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
```

You might want to look in `/etc/systemd` for the configuration files, such as `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf`.

Comment: Thanks. I actually solved the problem a little while ago by uninstalling and re-installing `network-manager`. At that time, I had forgotten about this AskUbuntu question. Interestingly, my `/etc/resolv.conf` right now is not a symbolic link. But I better not touch it as it currently works as expected.