# Google Account not working in fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: google, online-accounts

I did a fresh install of ubuntu 18.04 (binonic beaver) and everything is working smooth except I'm unable to sync with my google account/calendar.

When I navigate to Settings --> Online Accounts --> Google, the page load is very slow. Subsequently, after I enter my username, it just hangs at "Something went wrong"

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZtZM.png

I've found few issues related to this w.r.t gnome installation and apparently and a bug was filed against webkit2gtk. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/webkit2gtk/+bug/1687019. However as per that, latest version of webkit2gtk should fix this issue. I'm already on the latest version(I believe) of webkit2gtk.

```
➜  ~ sudo dpkg -l | grep libwebkit2gtk                        
ii  libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37:amd64                      2.22.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1              amd64        Web content engine library for GTK+
ii  libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37-gtk2:amd64                 2.22.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1              amd64        Web content engine library for GTK+ - GTK+2 plugin process
```

How do I get google account working ?

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the similar issue but without message "Something went wrong". In my case the Linux sign in dialogue didn't evolve after type password (full frozen white screen).
This erro was happen in this invironment:

> Operating System: Kubuntu 20.04
> KDE Plasma Version: 5.18.5 
> KDE Frameworks Version: 5.68.0 
> Qt Version: 5.12.8 
> Kernel Version: 5.4.0-71-generic 
> OS Type: 64-bit

And I resolved it with access to Google DisplayUnlockCaptcha in this link:
[https://accounts.google.com/b/**4**/DisplayUnlockCaptcha](https://accounts.google.com/b/4/DisplayUnlockCaptcha)

But pay attention: Change the number "**4**" in the url above for you desire account number, if you have more than one google account.

After access this link and click in "Continue" you will see the message: "account access allowed".
Then, go back to system settings in linux (my case is kubuntu), and try again:

```
System Settings > Personalization > Online Accounts > Add new Account > Google
```

And then may worked through the sign in dialogue in Evolution.
This got it up an running for me and for [user Simon in launchpad.net](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/webkit2gtk/+bug/1687019/comments/70).

Answer (score -1):

I spent days trying to figure it out. The problem was with the network configuration actually.

My syslog was full of warning like this:

`localhost systemd-resolved[1632]: Using degraded feature set (TCP) for DNS server 127.0.1.1`

This thread helped: [Syslog flooded with systemd-resolved messages "Using degraded feature set"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/932486/syslog-flooded-with-systemd-resolved-messages-using-degraded-feature-set)

In a gist:

1. Make sure your network manager wont update file you are about to modify by adding
   `dns=none` in `[main]` section of `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`
2. Look into `/etc/resolv.conf`. You will probably see the line about nameserver address. Remove or comment it.
3. Run `sudo service systemd-resolved restart` to be sure all is reloaded

Those steps made my problem with Google Account login go away.