# Stop network manager modifying resolve.conf in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, network-manager

Network manager keeps modifying resolve.conf and there is no stopping it in Ubuntu 18.04. I tried removing write permissions, change resolve.conf symlink to another file and... I also looked at [network manager: how to stop nm updating /etc/resolv.conf](https://askubuntu.com/questions/623940/network-manager-how-to-stop-nm-updating-etc-resolv-conf) but none of the solutions seems to be working in this Ubuntu version.

Comment: What don't you want it to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are various ways to configure NM not to touch `/etc/resolv.conf`:

```
[main]
dns=none
```

or (better)

```
[main]
rc-manager=unmanaged
```

in NetworkManager.conf. See `man NetworkManager.conf`.

You can also set `rc-manager=symlink`, and make `/etc/resolv.conf` a symlink pointing to a file (like systemd-resolved's stub resolve.conf). Well, you said, you tried this. Unclear, why that wouldn't work for you.

Or, you make the file immutable, with `chattr +i /etc/resolv.conf`.

Comment: I'd love your help on this related question. Thanks! https://askubuntu.com/questions/1453982/ubuntu-22-04-1-nameservers-keep-getting-overwritten