# NetworkManager resets resolv.conf on every reboot

Tags: 18.04, network-manager, resolv.conf

Why is netowrk manager resetting resolv.conf to 127.0.0.53

**resolv.conf**

```
# Generated by NetworkManager
nameserver 127.0.0.53
```

this causes internet to not work on my computer.

Answer (score 1):

One way to stop Network Manager from adding dns-servers to `/etc/resolv.conf` file is to do this. So first open the nm conf file `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`:

```
sudo vim /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

And add this to the `[main]` section:

```
dns=none
```

Save and exit.

**Source:**
[network manager: how to stop nm updating /etc/resolv.conf](https://askubuntu.com/questions/623940/network-manager-how-to-stop-nm-updating-etc-resolv-conf)

Comment: oh so is it that pi hole running on my computer may be resetting it , because in its dns setting I have Upstream dns server set to itself. `192.168.1.18#53`

Comment: No, Pi Hole doesn't reset this to default value. Please try what I said and let me know if it helps. Thanks

Comment: having done this using pi hole ip I am not able to access internet with pihole host ip configure as dns on the device I use.

Comment: This solved my issue on Ubuntu 20.04, thanks.