# Network Manager doesn't respect DHCP settings?

Tags: networking, 20.04, network-manager, dhclient

Had my Ubuntu 20.04 system running without any issues for months, but lately I had to start running `sudo dhclient` after every reboot, otherwise I am not able to connect to the internet.

I am fairly sure this issue has to do with my recent attempt at trying out Wireguard which I may have misconfigured resulting in a broken setting somewhere (Wireguard is now uninstalled).

Right after login, my network manager connection looks like this, which was identical when everything was running fine:

[image]
[image]

After running `sudo dhclient`, I have network but the network-manager settings haven't changed.

I could add the `dhclient` command to a startup script, but what I would really like is to understand what got messed up!

Here is my `/etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml` config

```yaml
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Edit: more details

I am connected to my router both through ethernet and wifi, and on startup only ethernet seems to have issues. My DHCP client is a pihole docker container running on a NAS on the LAN. My setup didn't change recently tho.

running `ifconfig`, these are the outputs for my `enp4s0` and `wlp5s0` interfaces:

```
enp4s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.108  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::e8fc:b999:680:6d7d  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 0c:9d:92:8a:c9:7a  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 631  bytes 563240 (563.2 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 1  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 578  bytes 65883 (65.8 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device memory 0xfc400000-fc41ffff  

enp4s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.108  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::e8fc:b999:680:6d7d  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 0c:9d:92:8a:c9:7a  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 631  bytes 563240 (563.2 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 1  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 578  bytes 65883 (65.8 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device memory 0xfc400000-fc41ffff
```

the output doesn't seem to change after running `sudo dhclient`, but I noticed one `RX dropped` error, and only on the ethernet interface.

Edit 2:

Looks like my `/etc/resolv.conf` file doesn't exist at startup (may be an obvious thing but better to add this info

before:

```
cat /etc/resolv.conf
```

after:

```
cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
# 127.0.0.53 is the systemd-resolved stub resolver.
# run "systemd-resolve --status" to see details about the actual nameservers.

nameserver 192.168.1.112
```

Edit 3:

my `/etc/systemd/network` folder is empty

running `sudo iptables -L` before and after running `dhclient` shows the following differences (only differences shown since I use PIA VPN and it adds a ton of entries, but it has been installed on my system for months too):

before:

```
Chain piavpn.r.300.allowLAN (1 references)
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             224.0.0.0/4         

[...]

This stuff below isn't present after running the command
Chain ufw-skip-to-policy-output (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
Chain ufw-track-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
Chain ufw-track-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
Chain ufw-track-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate NEW
Chain ufw-user-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
Chain ufw-user-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
Chain ufw-user-limit (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 5 LOG level warning prefix "[UFW LIMIT BLOCK] "
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
Chain ufw-user-limit-accept (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
Chain ufw-user-logging-forward (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
Chain ufw-user-logging-input (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
Chain ufw-user-logging-output (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
Chain ufw-user-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

after:

```
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             base-address.mcast.net/4 

[...]

entries missing
```

Let me know if you need other info

Answer (score 0):

After troubleshooting all day long, I just gave up: instead of understanding what was causing this issue I just fixed the problem even though I am 100% sure the issue comes from somewhere else:

Based on [this askubuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/623940/network-manager-how-to-stop-nm-updating-etc-resolv-conf) I removed the symlink from `/etc/resolv.conf` and added my own DNS entry. After a restart I noticed the file got replaced with one created by Network Manager, so I just updated that one.

Everything is back to normal, even though I am still unsure what caused all this mess.

Comment: So basically, you were correctly connected to the Internet all the time, only your DNS resolution wasn't working? That's always the first thing to try if you suppose you don't have Internet connection, ping some server by its IP address. Then you can right away narrow down the problem to DNS.

Comment: Remove the big banner at the end of the answer it does not add anything.

Comment: @raj the thing is that my dns server was set correctly if you check  the images (192.168.1.112 has always been the proper dns ip), but for some reason I couldn't actually send dns requests to it. At the end by checking the contents of `resolv.conf` I noticed that contrarily to what the gui was showing me I had no dns server set up. Since I never had this kind of issues I didn't expect the entire networking interface to basically report false information, hence expected dns to be reacheable

Comment: @David done, thank you for the feedback