# My university network is changing resolv.conf. How do I prevent that?

Tags: networking, network-manager, dns

When I connect to the internet in my university, through a PEAP, MSCHAPv2 protected WPA2 wifi network, it changes my resolv.conf to this:

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
# 127.0.0.53 is the systemd-resolved stub resolver.
# run "systemd-resolve --status" to see details about the actual nameservers.

nameserver 127.0.0.53
search ufsc.br
```

However, when I get home, I can't access the website as it tries to reach a local address which obviously isn't there. I have to manually remove the nameserver/search lines to be able to access it again.

My question is: what process is actually doing this - changing the file as I connect to my university's network? How can I find out which process is doing it and tell it to stop? Or, if this is necessary - how do I automatically roll the file back to an empty version when I leave the university's network?

Comment: You should probably have a look at https://askubuntu.com/questions/907246/how-to-disable-systemd-resolved-in-ubuntu

Comment: This seems to be the same problem as https://askubuntu.com/q/58781/696245

Comment: I'll take a look at the second one but the first one seems to break VPN functionality for some users, something I also use (the University's VPN).

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend to set a static IP through Network Manager first. Once connected to the network of your university, modify the settings going to the **IPv4** tab and choosing the **Manual** method. Press the **Add**  button and add your static IP.

Example:

**IP** 192.168.x.xxx

**Netmask** 255.255.255.0

**Gateway** 192.168.x.x

**Save** your new configuration

To know your Gateway digit the following command in a terminal:

```
route -n
```

The output of the command should be something like this:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.2.1     0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlp2s0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlp2s0
192.168.2.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlp2s0
```

As you can see my Gateway is 192.168.2.1 and the IP you will choose will be a 192.168.2.xxx ( example 192.168.2.100 ).

Disable the systemd-resolved service and stop it:

```
sudo systemctl disable systemd-resolved.service
sudo service systemd-resolved stop
```

Put the following line in the `[main]` section of your `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`:

```
dns=default
```

Install resolvconf:

```
sudo apt-get install resolvconf
```

and edit or create the file `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/tail`

```
sudo nano /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/tail
```

Add Google nameservers (one per line) to the file

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

Save the file pressing **Ctrl+O**

**RESTART YOUR SYSTEM** and connect to your network

Comment: This will probably break wifi functionality if they're in a University environment that is not wired.

Comment: @Thomas Ward . Why it should?

Comment: @Thomas Ward. I mean, it's my daily wireless configuration and i have no problems at all with it.

Comment: I should be able to try that on Monday!

Comment: This didn't work - not because the file was still changed, but because the internet didn't work at all. Maybe Ward was right and it did break wifi functionality.